# PDF (Prawn) : Generate tables without Prawnto

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, ruby-on-rails-2, prawn, prawnto

For some permission restriction, I can't install `prawnto` gem to my server. I used the method of http://blog.idyllic-software.com/blog/bid/204082/Creating-PDF-using-Prawn-in-Ruby-on-Rails to generate PDF for my object.

But, I used the method `pdf.table` to generate table, and this method is not accessible since I've remove `prawnto`.

Is there any method accessible to easily generate tables just with `prawn` gem ?

My application is on Rails 2.3.16, and `prawn` version 0.8.4.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to use prawn 0.8.4? If not then try to **upgrade to latest prawn**.

I am using prawn 0.12.0 and I can generate tables using `pdf.table` without `prawnto` gem.

Comment: Because I'm under Ruby 1.8.6, and this is the last version accessible.